# What does this command do?: `docker build . -f Dockerfile2 -t `

Tags: docker, dockerfile

From my tutorial, it creates clone Dockerfile (Dockerfile2) and build the second Docker.

`docker build . -f Dockerfile2 -t`

But I don't understand what `.` does.

According to Docker documentation.:
`-t` : tag ...
`-f` : file...

What is this command doing? - Thanks

Comment: The Docker documentation has complete documentation of all the CLI commands, including [docker build](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/build/).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Obviously the tag is missing. Anyway you're [telling Docker](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/build/):

> Hey Docker, [the current directory](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/build/#build-with-path) is your build context so copy everything from this location ([except](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/build/#use-a-dockerignore-file) the files and directories mentioned in the `.dockerignore` file) and build the image for me using the [instructions](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/build/#specify-a-dockerfile--f) from the `Dockerfile2` file. Also, please [tag it](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/build/#tag-an-image--t) using the provided tag so I can reference it easily.

If you ommit the file (drop the `-f argument`), then the default `Dockerfile` file is assumed.

Comment: oh actually the tag name was out of scope from the video. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

`.` means the current directory where you are. And the Dockerfile is in it. If you do not in the directory of the Dockerfile, you will get the error.

The full command : `docker build path -f Dockfile -t containerName`. Also the document [docker build [OPTIONS] PATH | URL | -](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/build/).

Comment: why do we need a `tag`? `-t`

Comment: It's a name for the container. You can take a look [here](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/build/).

Comment: `-t, --tag` is for naming the result image. You can name it however you want, for example: myimage:mytag

Comment: Thank you Charles!

Answer (score 1):

From the [Docker build documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/build/):

> **Usage:**
>   docker build [OPTIONS] PATH | URL | -

`build`: Build an image from a Dockerfile

`.`: Specifies that the `PATH` is `.`, and so all the files in the local directory get `tar` d and sent to the Docker daemon. The `PATH` specifies where to find the files for the “context” of the build on the Docker daemon.

`--file , -f`: Name of the Dockerfile (Default is ‘PATH/Dockerfile’).

`--tag , -t`: Name and optionally a tag in the ‘name:tag’ format. You can apply multiple tags to an image.

So, what is happening is: *Docker I want to build an image from a Dockerfile called  Dockerfile2 tagged with the value (you didn't set the value of the tag) in the current path.*

Comment: Wow I love Docker community! Thank you. I like the last part of the sentence: `what is happening is...`